# How to access angular.dart component´s attribute or method

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I defined an **angular.dart component** like this:

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'dartcomp',
    templateUrl: 'dartComp.html',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const
    { 
      'val' : '@val'
    }
)
class DartComp
{ 
  String val;
  calc(a,b) =>a+b;
}
```

the **usage in the HTML** is:

```html
 <dartcomp id="dc"></dartcomp>
```

How to access angular.dart component´s attribute val or method calc() from the main dart

a **call to the component** like

```dart
querySelector("#dc").val = "Frank";
```

throw:

Class 'UnknownElement' has no instance setter 'val='.

```
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'val='
Receiver: Instance of 'UnknownElement'
Arguments: ["Frank"]
```

What´s the mistake?

Comment: extended my answer with a proposed solution for calling methods on Angular components/directives

Comment: I extended index.dart to demonstrate how pass data and callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Accessing attributes like class properties works in Polymer but not in Angular.Dart.
You have to use the Elements default method `.attributes['attrName'] = value`

```dart
// this doesn't work with Angular
//    querySelector("#dc").attributes['val'] = "Frank";

// I found an AngularDart function that may help but it's comment says this is for debugging only
// this example calls the method 'add' on MyComponent
  var mc = ngProbe(dom.querySelector('my-component')).directives.firstWhere((d) => d is MyComponent);
  mc.add('someValue');
```

Maybe there is a better way I'm not aware of, but this way should work at any rate.

**workaround for calling methods on Angular components/controllers**

**Example is also available here:** [GitHub BWU-Dart Playground](https://github.com/bwu-dart/angular_playground/tree/master/web/call_method_from_main)

This is the best idea I come up with.
Maybe someone of the AngularDart creators knows a better solution.
(I also couldn't find a straight forward solution for AngularJS)

**EventBus**

```dart
/**
 * Derived from https://github.com/marcojakob/dart-event-bus
 */

library eventbus;

import "dart:async";
import "dart:html";

import "package:logging/logging.dart";

/**
 * [EventBus] is a central event hub.
 * In addition it automatically updates the page navigation history ([History]
 * by calling [window.pushState] for fired events which indicate, that they
 * are supposed to update the [History] and refiring events which led to
 * [window.pushState] in the case of a [window.onPopState] event.
 */
class EventBus extends Object {
  final _logger = new Logger("EventBusModel");

  /**
   * A [StreamController] is maintained for each event type.
   */
  Map<EventType, StreamController> streamControllers = new Map<EventType, StreamController>();

  bool isSync = true;

  /**
   * Constructs an [EventBus] and allows to specify if the events should be
   * send synchroniously or asynchroniously by setting [isSync].
   */
  EventBus({this.isSync : false});

  /**
   * [on] allows to access an stream for the specified [eventType].
   */
  Stream/*<T>*/ on(EventType/*<T>*/ eventType) {
    _logger.finest('on');

    return streamControllers.putIfAbsent(eventType, () {
      return new StreamController.broadcast(sync: isSync);
      }
    ).stream;
  }

  /**
   * [fire] broadcasts an event of a type [eventType] to all subscribers.
   */
  void fire(EventType/*<T>*/ eventType, /*<T>*/ data) {
    _logger.finest('event fired: ${eventType.name}');

    if (data != null && !eventType.isTypeT(data)) {
      throw new ArgumentError('Provided data is not of same type as T of EventType.');
    }

    var controller = streamControllers[eventType];
    if (controller != null) {
      controller.add(data);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Type class used to publish events with an [EventBus].
 * [T] is the type of data that is provided when an event is fired.
 */
class EventType<T> {

  String name;

  /**
   * Constructor with an optional [name] for logging purposes.
   */
  EventType(this.name);

  /**
   * Returns true if the provided data is of type [T].
   *
   * This method is needed to provide type safety to the [EventBus] as long as
   * Dart does not support generic types for methods.
   */
  bool isTypeT(data) => data is T;
}
```

**index.dart** with **MyComponent** and **main()**

```dart
library main;

import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:di/di.dart';

import 'event_bus.dart';

class Item {
  String name;
  Item(this.name);
}

@NgComponent(
    selector: 'my-component',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    applyAuthorStyles: true,
    template: '''<div ng-repeat="value in ctrl.values"><span>{{value.name}}</span> - <content><content></div>'''
)

class MyComponent {
  List<Item> values = [new Item('1'), new Item('2'), new Item('3'), new Item('4')];

  void add(String value) {
    values.add(new Item(value));
  }

  EventBus _eb;

  MyComponent(this._eb) {
    print('MyComponent');
    _eb.on(Events.someEvent).listen((e) => add(e));
    _eb.on(Events.someEventWithData).listen((SomeEventData ed) {
      print('Event received from ${ed.senderId}');
      ed.respond(this);
    });
  }
}


typedef MyComponentEventResponse (MyComponent component);
class SomeEventData {
  SomeEventData(this.respond, this.someOtherData, [this.senderId]);
  MyComponentEventResponse respond;
  var someOtherData;
  String senderId;
}

class Events {
  static final EventType<String> someEvent = new EventType<String>("someEvent");
  static final EventType<SomeEventData> someEventWithData = new EventType<SomeEventData>("someEventWithData");
}

class MyAppModule extends Module {
  MyAppModule() {
    type(MyComponent);
    value(EventBus, new EventBus());
  }
}

void main() {
  Injector inj = ngBootstrap(module: new MyAppModule());

  EventBus eb = inj.get(EventBus);

  eb.fire(Events.someEvent, "17");
  new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () => eb.fire(Events.someEvent, "33"));
  new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () => eb.fire(Events.someEventWithData, new SomeEventData(respond, 'blabla', 'main105')));
}

void respond(MyComponent c) {
  dom.window.alert('Demonstrate access to event receiver: Name of 2nd item: ${c.values[1].name}');
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>

    <h3>Repeat</h3>
    <my-component>
      <div>some provided content to repeat</div>
    </my-component>

    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Of course it does. The line in my answer is the line from the question that contains the error with the correction applied. I wrote it from my phone so it got a bit short. I'll extend it a bit.

Comment: Somehow this answer was flagged as low-quality.  I'm sure @tepkenvannkorn did not study the answer well enough.  Tho, perhaps extending it a bit would help. :)

Comment: Tnx! can I also call methods of the component from the main dart program?

Comment: I wondered about this too but hadn't yet time to take a look how this might work. I'll try it and extend the answer when I find a solution.

Comment: Tnx! Can the attribute to access via .attributes['attrname'] be an object too?

Comment: No only String. I thought about this too, to provide a callback.

Comment: Eventbus Example: How would I distinguish two instances of my_component for sending the event? Can I get an object as an answer of an event?

Comment: In the updated example the event receiver sends itself back to the sender.

Comment: I tried the first solution: querySelector("#dc").attributes['val'] = "Frank"; but it didn´t work. my components html is: <span> val:{{ctrl.val}}:   </span>

Comment: You're right. AngularDart doesn't care about attribute value changes from the 'outside' (same in AngularJS). I change my answer.

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of.

Comment: so I expect we would have the same effect with your eventbus approach if the called method changes an attribute - no change in the view

Comment: I thought the eventbus approach was to replace attribute changes. I'm positive that other Angular components/directives would recognize the attribute changes but it seems Angular doesn't care much about the 'outside' world. It just seems to require that all has to be done the Angular way.

Comment: You should probably revoke the 'accept answer' so others my take an effort to answer the question. Maybe someone from the Dart team knows better ways. (you can later accept it again of course if nothing better comes up)

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different approach.

In a static map in the component I store the instances of the components, so that I can access the component later in the main.dart

```dart
@NgComponent(
    selector: 'dartcomp',
    templateUrl: 'dartComp.html',
    publishAs: 'ctrl',
    map: const
    { 'val' : '@val',
      'id'  : '@id'
    }

)
class DartComp implements NgAttachAware
{ static Map<String,DartComp> comp = new Map();

  String id;
  String val;

  void attach()
  { comp[id]=this; }
}
```

the components html:

```html
<span> Component val:{{ctrl.val}}:   </span>
```

In the index.html I put 2 of the components

```html
<dartcomp id="dc1"></dartcomp>
<dartcomp id="dc2" val="max"></dartcomp>
```

In the main.dart I try to change the val attribute of component dc1

```dart
DartComp.comp['dc1'].val="frank";
```

but in the browser I can't see change.
Is there a way to solve the problem like this?

Comment: I thought about this too, but you have to be careful to not create a memory leak. Elements assigned to this map can't be garbage collected. Even when they are removed from the DOM they stay in memory.