# Catch exception from nested polymer element in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I can't figure out how to catch an exception thrown by a nested Element.

What I want is something like:

```html
<error-handler>
    <hard-worker></hard-worker>
</error-handler>
```

The idea is, for example, to make a REST-Request in hard-worker. If hard-worker gets an error from the REST-Server, of course, it makes its own error handling. But finally it has to display an error message somewhere / somehow. error-handler is thought to be the one who shows the error (Exception) to the user. error-handler should be changeable. It could be for example error-handler-log-message or error-handler-show-popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Polymer-Sample on GitHub.
It shows the two discussed approaches: Eventbus-Based (was already there) and the new DOM-Event approach. (The one I prefer - much cleaner)

Working sample (Chrome)
https://rawgithub.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerHelloWorld/master/build/index.html

The code:
https://github.com/MikeMitterer/DART-Sample-PolymerHelloWorld/tree/master/web

Some details about what I did:
**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="hello-world/hello-world.html">
    <link rel="import" href="event-handler/event-handler.html">
    <link rel="import" href="stopwatch/stopwatch.html">
    <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Hi first world!</h1>
    <!-- event-handler should show some events coming in from hello-world -->
    <event-handler>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </event-handler>

    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**hello-world.html**
Element that fires an event if you click the "Fire an event"-button. This could also be an error-message...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<polymer-element name="hello-world">
    <template>
        <button on-click="{{increment}}">Click Me</button>
        <button on-click="{{fireevent}}">Fire an event (received by event-handler)</button>

        <p>Hello from inside a custom element! Clicks: {{count}}</p>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="hello-world.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**hello-world.dart**

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:event_bus/event_bus.dart';
import 'package:PolymerHelloWorld/globaleventbus.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:json/json.dart' as JSON;

@CustomTag('hello-world')
class HelloWorldElement extends PolymerElement {
    final EventBus _eventbus = new GlobalEventBus();

    @observable int count = 0;

    HelloWorldElement.created() : super.created();

    void increment(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
        count += 1;
        _eventbus.fire(GlobalEventBus.basicClickEvent,"Test");
    }

    void fireevent(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        final Map json = { 'response' : 'Hi, this is a message', 'random' : random.nextInt(100)};

        // Fires a JSON-Message 
        fire("hello-event",detail: JSON.stringify(json));
    }
}
```

**event-handler.html**
Template that receives the "hello-event"

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<polymer-element name="event-handler" on-hello-event="{{handleHelloEvent}}">
    <template>
        <style>
            .error { color: red; }
        </style>
        <p class="error">EventHandler (Shows hello-world events!) Message: {{response}}, Random number: {{randomnumber}}</p>
        <content></content>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="event-handler.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

**event-handler.dart**
Implements the **handleHelloEvent** defined in the according template

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:json/json.dart' as JSON;

@CustomTag('event-handler')
class EventHandler  extends PolymerElement {

    @observable String response = "";
    @observable int randomnumber = 0;

    EventHandler.created() : super.created();

    void handleHelloEvent(Event e, var detail, Node target) {
        final Map json = JSON.parse(detail);

        response = json['response'];
        randomnumber = json['random'];

        // Log to console 
        print("Received event! $detail");
    }
}
```

That's it - if you know how it works - as easy as pie!

Answer (score 0):

That won't work as the code in `<hard-worker>` is not invoked from `<error-handler>`.

It would be helpful if you provided more information about what kind of errors you want to handle in `<error-handler>`.

If you have code that is error-prone you should it encapsulate with a try-catch hand handle the error as locally to the cause as possible.

**EDIT** (after comment)

That makes more sense. But do you really want to have such an error handler for one service? I would rather have such an error handler for the page (maybe different for visible controls like form text input)

I suggest you use something like an `Eventbus` (see an example on the answer to this question [How to access angular.dart component´s attribute or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151560)) to send `Error` events and let the `<error-handler>` listen to such events. The events can contain additional data in the `details` property like message, severity, ...

Comment: IMHO it would be better to extend/improve your question instead of commenting. I just saw that you already got downvoted.
see also my extended answer

Comment: EventBus was/is my Plan B - I just thought there must be something build into polymer which supports exception handling over element borders - seems not the case. BTW I'm using this EventBus: http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/event_bus - works nice.

Comment: The EventBus example I linked to is a simplified version of this EventBus package (the code has a reference to the GitHub repo). 
Polymer is more to build standalone elements/widgets not an application framework hence the missing of such functionality.

Comment: I know it's not an application framework but in the end some polymer elements have to work together. What I don't like in the EventBus approach is the tight coupling between EventBus an Element. Take a widget library in polymer - it should be universal but how can it be useful if there is no error handling approach?

Comment: You can expose an elements attribute that references an observable list of its errors and an error handling element that binds to this attribute.

Comment: Uhhh... I think I get closer to what I'm looking for. <polymer-ajax> fires some events. http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/#polymer-ajax - I'll investigate into this.

Comment: Yes custom DOM events is an option too.

Here is the Dart version https://github.com/ErikGrimes/polymer_elements/tree/master/lib/polymer_ajax

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<polymer-element name="event-handler" on-hello-event="{{handleHelloEvent}}">
```

I think you can use (but didn't try):

```
<event-handler>
  <hello-world on-hello-event="{{handleHelloEvent}}"></hello-world>
</event-handler>
```

Your component does not need to know which method has to be called !

Also you don't need to stringify your map: detail accepts any kind of Object