# Can't access member variables of objects in List in dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a list of teams in my component. These teams are listed in the html-template for the component. I've created add and update functions and they are working, but if I try to access a member variable of team i get the error: NoSuchMethodError: undefined is not a function:

```dart
void delete(int id, String name, int onlineId){
Team tempTeam;
  html.window.console.info("In delete()");
  for(int i = 0; i < teamList.length; i++){
    if(teamList.elementAt(i).id == selectedTeam){ // <-- this fails
      tempTeam = teamList.elementAt(i);
    }
  }
  ...
  html.window.console.info("Deleting team: " + name + " succeded!");
}
```

Here is the component:

```dart
@Component(
    selector: 'admin-teams-view',
    templateUrl: 'packages/fremad/components/admin/teams_view.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/fremad/components/admin/teams_view.css',
    useShadowDom: false
)
class ShowAdminTeamsComponent {
  List<Team> teamList;
  int selectedTeam = -1;
  bool isEditing = false;
  ...
}
```

Here are the html of interest

```dart
<li ng-repeat="team in teamList">
  <div class="item-name" ng-click="selectTeam(team.id)">
  {{team.name}}
  </div>
  <div class="item-edit" ng-hide="isActive(team.id)">
    <form>
      Name:
      <input type="text" size="35" ng-model="team.name">
      Online ID:
      <input type="number" size="15" ng-model="team.onlineId">
      <input type="button" class="adminButton redButton" value="delete" ng-click="delete(team.id, team.name, team.onlineId)">
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

I will be thankful for any help!

From console after doing print(teamList[i]) and print(teamList[i].name):

```dart
{id: 1, name: Fremad Famagusta Menn Senior A, onlineId: 30296} js_primitives.dart:25
NoSuchMethodError: undefined is not a function

STACKTRACE:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at dart.J.get$name$x (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:40910:39)
    at ShowAdminTeamsComponent.delete$3 (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:34640:22)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:2922:12), <anonymous>:2:42)
    at dart.Primitives_applyFunction (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:2609:23)
    at StaticClosureMap_lookupFunction_closure.call$3 (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:11389:18)
    at ClosureMapLocalsAware_lookupFunction_closure.call$3 (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:9546:79)
    at CallScope.methodClosure$3 (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:9851:33)
    at CallScope.eval$2 (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:9868:19)
    at _UnwrapExceptionDecorator.eval$2 (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:9359:31)
    at _UnwrapExceptionDecorator.eval$2 [as eval$1] (http://localhost:8080/fremad/fremad_main.dart.js:9372:19)
```

Edit:
This is how my TeamList is loaded:

```dart
void loadData() {
  tableLoaded = false;
  _http.get('rest/team/getTeams.json')
    .then((HttpResponse response) {
      teamListObject = new TeamList.fromJson(response.data);
      teamList = teamListObject.teamList;
      tableLoaded = true;
      html.window.console.info("Success on loading table");
    })
    .catchError((e) {
      print(e);
      tableLoaded = false;
    });
}
```

And this is the class:

```dart
class TeamList {
  bool empty;
  List<Team> teamList;

  TeamList(this.empty, this.teamList);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => <String, dynamic>{
    "emtpy" : empty,
    "listObject": teamList
  };

  TeamList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : this( 
      json['empty'], json['listObject']);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a similar issue https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1573

Comment: It could be.. But I'm going to give it one more try before I report the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the fromJson in the TeamList class:

```
TeamList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) : this( 
    json['empty'], new List<Team>.from(json['listObject'].map((x) => new Team.fromJson(x))));
```

Dart does not understand nested classes in that way. You have tried to access the map listObject as a map, not a List.

Answer (score 0):

What exact error message do you get ?
You should try dumping the list and the index in the for loop - using print().

Answer (score -1):

Try to read the answer [How to access angular.dart component´s attribute or method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151560/how-to-access-angular-dart-component%C2%B4s-attribute-or-method)

from [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%C3%BCnter-z%C3%B6chbauer)

Comment: This does not help me in this case. My problem is not accessing the HTML-scope, but to access the member variable of Team in List<Team>